# PHP/JS script is not working inside HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am adding an upload function to the HTML div, but for some reason it is not working. I have also created a php file with the same scripts I have added to the div and did the action="upload-page.php", but it does not get the php page either. What could be the problem?
Here is the code:

```php
<div class="wall-ptype-cnt wall_text" >
__post_wall_text__
<form method="post" action="upload-page.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" type="file" multiple="" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var input = document.getElementById('filesToUpload');
    var list = document.getElementById('fileList');


    while (list.hasChildNodes()) {
    list.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
    }


    for (var x = 0; x < input.files.length; x++) {

        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = 'File ' + (x + 1) + ':  ' + input.files[x].name;
        list.append(li);
    }           
</script>
<?php if(count($_FILES['uploads']['filesToUpload'])) {
foreach ($_FILES['uploads']['filesToUpload'] as $file) {

    //do your upload stuff here
    echo $file;

        }
    }
?>
</form>
</div>
```

Why does the php page is not being processed and why the script is not working as well?
The script I have in upload-page.php is the same I am putting inside html.

Comment: I haven't really read this through but first of all your javascript should be contained in a `window.onload = function() {`

Comment: You need to tell it where to upload your files in the section marked `//do your upload stuff here`. There is nothing showing where your files are uploaded to, unless you're not showing us your entire code. Consult the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: you don't have any "fileList" id element in the page so you might get js error

Comment: I included my js inside window.onload function() {},still not working the way it should. It is the full code. Before I tried to add uploadify or uploadifive inside my html div, and it was not working for me either..

Answer (score 1):

A couple of mistakes in your code:

1. "`list.removeChild(ul.firstChild);`" should be "`list.removeChild(list.firstChild);`"

   "`list.append(li);`" should be "`list.appendChild(li);`"